# Resolving a String representation of a class to an actual type

Tags: java

I am working with a third-party system which, internally, records object types as primitive Strings, for example "com.example.MyClass".

I need to find a way to resolve such a String into an *actual* corresponding type. In the example here, for example, I want to get the equivalent of just writing MyClass.class.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you have issues with the choice of the proper classloader, this is enough:

```
Class.forName(string);
```